# Yepnope callback always returns 'result = false'

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, loader, yepnope

Here's the code, there's a prefix that defines local! but that's it. No matter what, the second argument in the callback is always false whether it loads correctly or not.

Also window.jQuery always returns undefined, so I have no idea whats going on

```
    yepnope([
        {
            load: {
                "style" : "css!<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>",
                "fonts" : "timeout=4000!css!http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/fonts/fonts-min.css",
                "jquery" : "timeout=4000!//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js",
                "fbSDK" : "local!/js/FBsdk.js",
                "detect" : "local!/js/detectDevice.js",
            },
            callback: {
                "fonts": function() {
                    console.log(arguments);// the second argument is
                },                         // always false
                "jquery": function() {
                    if ( !window.jQuery ) {
                        yepnope('local!/js/jQuery-1.7.js');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry Marius, I did some tests and your code works (jQuery is loaded and executed). But you are right about the second argument, always false. But yepnope doc says "Another thing you might want to know in this situation is the result of your test. Luckily, that's the second parameter. [..]". The only way where I caught an undefined jQuery was when I forgot I was running "file:///...html" :-). In a project, I noticed on IE & FF when Etags are activated and I receive a 304, jQuery is undefined in the complete callback, but executed just after (Not with Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped on this one also - turns out that if you don't have a test condition in your object (which your above example does not) i.e.

test: Modernizr.geolocation,

the result will always return false. It doesn't mean that the script include failed.